# Allow moderators to edit the sidebar text on the ask page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

**TL;DR:** Moderators should be given the ability to edit the sidebar text on /questions/ask.

---

Moderators can edit various documents and texts around their sites that the community can't. The help center's /on-topic page is a good example of this. This is good, because it lets the community make changes to their documentation faster than any other process would allow.

I propose that this functionality be extended to the sidebar on the ask page.

#### What's the Problem?

The 'problem' with the current system isn't so much of a problem as an inefficiency.

To edit that text, the current method is:

- create a meta post to confirm with the community that they want this to happen, and to get the wording of the text down
- go bug a community manager to edit the text for you
- wait for the edit to come through

Now, while this isn't a *massive* problem, it *does* reduce communities' self-sufficiency and efficiency, which can in turn be a problem when sites want to take action on question quality and this turns out to be a holding point.

I've seen a couple of cases recently where sites have had that text edited, which as with many CM requests is unpredictable - without *any* disrespect to the CM's, they have many tasks on their plates and can't always deal with individual issues like this straight away. It can take a while for things to happen, in some cases.

#### What's the Solution?

The current mod-editing functionality could be extended to cover this text as well. If you haven't figured it out yet, it's this I'm talking about:

[image]

This would allow mods to edit the text there without having to go through CM requests.

This would solve the issue - moderators are more familiar with their sites, scopes, and communities than the CM's are. This is an advantage because it removes the time taken for a CM to familiarise themselves with a site or issue, then evaluate the proposal, then provide feedback or action.

I have been told of a couple of potential reasons why this shouldn't happen:

- **There's generally no reason to be making rapid changes to that text.**
  Neither is there a reason to do so in the help center. Mods have access to edit the help center, and that's a very useful feature. I don't *think* I've heard of any cases of abuse of it?
- **It's something everyone asking sees, and the CM's want to be on top of it.**
  That is, of course, up to the CM's. However, I believe that currently, when mods edit the help center, the CM's are pinged in some way (email, inbox, I don't know). Perhaps it would be a good idea, if mods were given this access, to extend this ping too? When a mod edits the text, a CM can be pinged about it and review it.

Some other thoughts I had about the implementation of this:

- Perhaps it could be rate-limited, so that it *can't* be edited very frequently. Use a long rolling rate limit - one edit per 24 hours?
- Perhaps something similar could be used for edits here as for revision redactions and close reason additions? When a mod edits the text, generate an auto-flag for another mod to review.

Comment: If they're concerned about rogue mods changing it, remember that off topic reasons need more than 1 mod to vote in favour of the change

Comment: Do moderators have ways to precisely measure the impact of such changes? Usually any community tends to expand warnings and notices more and more until they become pointless walls of text.

Comment: Is this request still valid/applicable? The guidance now shown on the `/questions/ask` page doesn't really look the same anymore; it *can* be customized on a per-site basis, just by staff (at the community's request) rather than by the site mods themselves.